# highcharts live update and YII framework

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have to display some sensors data using highcharts and 
I'm using YII as php framework.
I store the time in mysql (v5.6) as timestamp(3) I need the millisecond fraction
and I want to use it  because almost of my data are in one second or 2

my controller give me as output
      `["2012-12-01 15:00:00.070",45]` 
but this point is not shown  in my chart , and the ajax request is made just one time 
I get the error with firebug at the level of  "  var series = chart.series[0], "
I don't know if the problem is in my highchart code or in the time format 
I don't know also how to use the Dateparse inside my code after receiving the point 
 please help !

```
function requestData() {
 $.ajax ({
            type:"get" ,
        url: "<?php echo CController::createUrl('beam/GetSensorsDataLive') ?>",
        data: {"beamId" : "<?php echo $modelBeam['poutre_id'] ?>" },
         dataType: "json",

          success: function(response,point) {
          var series = chart.series[0], //// error here 

    shift = series.data.length > 20;// shift if the series is longer than 20
          chart.series[0].addPoint( point,true, false); // add the point
          setTimeout(requestData, 1000);    // call it again after one second

                                   },
                                 cache: false
    });
           }  

 $(document).ready(function() {
     var chart;

        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'graph',
            type: 'spline',
            events: {
                load: requestData   
            }
        },

        xAxis: {
          type: 'datetime',
          },
              tooltip: {

                  formatter: function() {

                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+

                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S:%m', this.x) +'<br/>'+

                    Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);

            }

        },  


                    series: [{
            name: 'Live Data From sensor <?php echo $modelBeam['poutre_id'] ;?>  ',
             data:[] 
        }]

    });

});
```

Comment: You "get the error with Firebug"... what is the *actual* error message you get? The current problem is that the `chart` variable is not visible in that scope. Move the `function requestData()` to inside the `$(document).ready(function() { })` block, so it can access `chart`.

Comment: hi !really many thanks,you save me
I cant see the all request in firebug now, but the point still not displayed as shown in this image 
http://i45.tinypic.com/2rhwbpk.png
normally without the update of my database, the request should get always the same point and display it and i get on point in the center of my chart, but in my case it looks like there is many point without display.
many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data x should be JS timestamp in miliseconds, also you can parse your data from php and use Date.UTC() function.